# Regex python : find different forms of currency with amount

Tags: python, regex, currency

I try to find the amounts in euros in receipts. 
I extract the values, but the currency can appear in different ways: "EUR", "E" or"€". I do not succeed in specifying these different forms within the regex. In addition, the "E" must not raise words that also begin with "E" such as "Eggs".

Currently my regex is `\d+[\.+\,+]\d*\s*[(e|eur|euros|€)]+\W` but the brackets don't work correctly because it retrieves all the words that contains E...

My goal: find the amounts if we find the form amount + EUR or amount + € or amount + E

See here an example : https://regex101.com/r/F3Zm9M/2

Thank you

Comment: Your regex is very chaotic, I think you you should look at examples on this website.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things going on here. 
First, you're not capturing what I think you want to capture (you said the values). You should have something like `(\d+(?:.|,)\d\d)` (the ?: inside the inner parentheses groups the . and , without making it another capturing group). 
Second, your [(e|eur|euros|€)] is not doing at all what you want it to - look at the explanation on the side panel of regex101 that you linked. What you want instead is just `e|eur|euros|€`. Again, in order to group these and have the `|` work like you want, you group them, and I'm assuming you don't want to capture these symbols, so use `(?:e|eur|euros|€)`. You might want to think about adding spaces to make sure the 'e' or 'eur' isn't inside a word, though then you might not match something like 'EUR3000'.
Overall, I'm not sure entirely what you're trying to match, but I hope this helps you get started.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain I understood the issue perfectly, but would this work : https://regex101.com/r/wRJeeS/1 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
r=r"(\d+[\.,\d]*)\s*(e|eur|euros|€|euro)(?:\s|$)"

s=" 123,456.47 E 123,456.47 Euro 123,456.47 137€ 138 € 139 euro 123,456.47€"

re.findall(r,s,flags=re.I)
Out: 
[('123,456.47', 'E'),
 ('123,456.47', 'Euro'),
 ('137', '€'),
 ('138', '€'),
 ('139', 'euro'),
 ('123,456.47', '€')]
```

- \d+[.,\d]*  at least one digit optionally followed by . , or other digits;
- \s|$  space or end of string;
- ( ) (?: )  capturing or
  non-capturing groups;
- re.I case insensitive